# What is the canonical way to allocate and construct polymorphic objects in Fortran?

Tags: oop, constructor, fortran, polymorphism

I want to create an array of polymorphic objects which have constructors taking different dummy arguments depending on their dynamic type. Having read about user-defined and structure constructors, I see no way to apply these concepts to dynamically allocated objects. Having a background in C++, I was used to the notion that I could use one and the same constructor "member function" when allocating objects either dynamically or on the stack, but how can I explicitly call user-defined Fortran constructors on allocated objects?

Instead, I tried to fiddle with generic and type-bound init functions:

```
module mod
type :: basis_t
contains
    procedure, public :: init_func => init_base
    ! I want a generic constructor function
    generic, public   :: init => init_func 
end type

type, extends(basis_t) :: extended_t
contains
    ! cannot work, init_extended has a different signature from init_base
    procedure, public :: init => init_extended 
end type

type wrapper_t
   type(basis_t), pointer :: obj
end type

contains
   subroutine init_base(this)
      class(base_t), intent(inout) :: this
   end subroutine

   subroutine init_extended(this, param)
      class(extended_t), intent(inout) :: this
      integer :: param
   end subroutine
end module

program
   use mod
   implicit none

   type(wrapper_t) :: arr(2)
   allocate(basis_t::arr(1)%obj)
   allocate(extended_t::arr(2)%obj)
   call arr(1)%obj%init    ! calls init_basis
   call arr(2)%obj%init(4) ! calls init_extended
end program
```

But I don't believe that I am on the right track, as in e.g. C++ I would rather do e.g.

```
basis_t* arr[2];
arr[0] = new basis_t;
arr[1] = new extended_t{ 4 };
```

The important difference is that the constructors in C++ are **not** type-bound/virtual, as in my Fortran approach. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The role of a constructor in Fortran can be provided by:

- The language provided *structure constructor*.
- A function with a result that is of the type of the object being constructed.  The language allows a generic function to have the same name as a derived type, and further allows a reference to such a function to overload what would otherwise be a reference to a structure constructor for the type.
- A subroutine that defines an intent(out) argument of the appropriate type.

What you use depends on circumstances and personal preference to an extent.  The language provided structure constructor can be used in constant expressions in some circumstances, but only permits simple value definition of components (no executable code); the function reference form permits you to execute arbitrary code as part of object construction, cannot be used in constant expressions, cannot easily indicate construction failure and might be expensive (depending on Fortran processor implementation details) if the constructed object is large; the subroutine form requires a separate call statement (the constructor cannot be part of a larger expression) and cannot take advantage of the generic name/structure overload language feature.

None of those three methods involve a type bound procedure.  There are some circumstances where a type bound procedure might be appropriate for object definition (a type bound procedure intended to read an object value from a file, for example - all types in the extension hierarchy require the same information about the file to be passed to them), but it doesn't make general sense for construction, where you are defining the type of the object as well as defining its value.

Pointers in Fortran are mostly used for reference semantics (because they are references).  You generally do not want to use them if you want value semantics - use allocatables.

```
TYPE :: ta
  INTEGER :: a
END TYPE ta

TYPE, EXTENDS(ta) :: tb
  REAL :: b
END TYPE :: tb

INTERFACE tb
  PROCEDURE :: tb_construct
END INTERFACE tb

TYPE, EXTENDS(ta) :: tc
END TYPE tc

TYPE :: ta_item
  CLASS(ta), ALLOCATABLE :: item
END TYPE ta_item

!...

FUNCTION tb_construct(arg)
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: arg
  TYPE(tb) :: tb_construct
  tb_construct%a = arg + 1
  tb_construct%b = arg / 2.0
END FUNCTION tb_construct

SUBROUTINE ConstructTC(obj, arg, stat)
  CLASS(ta), INTENT(OUT), ALLOCATABLE :: obj
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: arg
  INTEGER, INTENT(OUT) :: stat
  TYPE(tc), ALLOCATABLE :: tmp
  IF (arg < 0) THEN
    ! Construction failed.
    stat = 1
    RETURN
  END IF
  tmp%a = arg + 4
  CALL MOVE_ALLOC(tmp, obj)
  stat = 0    ! Construction succeeded.
END SUBROUTINE ConstructTC

!...

TYPE(ta_item) :: the_items(3)
INTEGER :: stat

! Structure constructor
the_items(1)%item = ta(1)

! Overloaded function.
the_items(2)%item = tb(2)

! Subroutine.
CALL ConstructTC(the_items(3)%item, 3, stat)
IF (stat /= 0) ERROR STOP 'It failed.'
```

Comment: Thanks for your enlightening answer, this exactly fulfills my needs. However, while I can compile this code with GCC's gfortran, the Intel compiler ifort 16.0.0 (to which I am bound) will throw the diagnostics `error #8304: In an intrinsic assignment statement, variable shall not be polymorphic.   [ITEM]
the_items(1)%item = ta(1)` and `error #6197: An assignment of different structure types is invalid.
the_items(2)%item = tb(2)`. I am sure at some point I've already tried your approach, but stumbled upon this issue, ignorant of recognizing this to be a compiler bug. Any ideas?

Comment: Intrinsic assignment to a polymorphic allocatable is a F2008 feature not available in that version of the compiler (19.0 is current, 20.0 due out shortly).  If you are using a structure constructor or function to construct the object, use the SOURCE specifier of the ALLOCATE statement, i.e. `ALLOCATE(the_items(1)%item, SOURCE=ta(...))`